# what is best way to set dynamic print range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is my current code and I have tried various combinations but it only prints the info in Columns A and B and ignores all data in Columns D to O

```
Sheets("PartsList").Select
Dim LstRw As Long, PrnG As Range
    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set PrnG = Range("A15:O15" & LstRw)
    
    
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = PrnG
```

Comment: This may not fix your issue, but i think you mean this: `Range("A15:O" & LstRw)` -Otherwise the result would be `A15:O15100` if there were 100 rows used in column A.

Comment: PrintArea property takes a string so you can try `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A15:O" & LstRw`, no need to set a range. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea)

Comment: Hi Raymond Thank you. I have tried your suggestion but it only selects the information in Columns A and B and prints them not all columns to column O

Comment: @JackvanHoof I just tested it and it works, try the code in the answer below and see if it works. Note that it only sets the print area, if you need the printing to be fixed on 1 page etc then you need to change other properties.

Answer (score 0):

`PrintArea` property takes a `String` value so you can pass the range directly to the property ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea)):

```
Sub Test()
    Const printRng As String = "A15:O"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PartsList")
    
    Dim LstRw As Long
    LstRw = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = printRng & LstRw
    
    Debug.Print ws.PageSetup.PrintArea
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Raymond Thank you once again. I copied your code and still didn't work. I am only a beginner in VBA but I find it very frustrating when both codes you gave me don't work and yet I am sure that they should work. I find VBA very difficult to understand when it seems so simple and direct and logical and yet it fails. Once again I really appreciate your assistance

Comment: @JackvanHoof Try this code on a new workbook and see if it works, what is the address printed out in the immediate window?